# reset browser to normal size in FF and Chrome

Tags: browser

in FF and Chrome, when you press ctrl+mouse wheel to zoom in and out.

How do you reset browser to normal size.

In IE it shows zoom percentage, but no idea if I have correct resolution in FF or Chrome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FF - <kbd>Ctrl + 0</kbd>

I don't know about chrome.